# Mysql, Insert into table from every record from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables like this:

```
table_com
-------------
id_com|code|value|
----------------
1     |10  | A
2     |20  | B


table_b
----------
id_b|code
----------
1   |10
2   |20
3   |30
```

I want to insert into `table_com` each registry that exists in `table_b`, but not in `table_com` (acording to `code`), in the example will be the `id_b==3`, because that code = 30 it is not present in `table_a`, and for the value, I need to put  0. The final `table_com` should be like this:

```
table_com
-------------
id_com|code|value|
-----------------
1     |10  | A
2     |20  | B
3     |30  | 0
```

I'm working with php, I tried a foreach value of the table_b and tried to insert values as I said, but not sure how to do it (I know that with INSERT INTO I can't use WHERE, that's just an example):

```
foreach ($comunas as $key => $value) {
            $code = $value->code;
            DB::select(DB::raw(" 
                INSERT INTO rgl_clientes_comuna (
                    code,
                    value
                ) 
                VALUES
                    ($code, 0,)
                WHERE code IS NOT $code
            "));
        }
```

EDIT:

1) For the first answer, I tried this (with my real data):

```
INSERT INTO rgl_clientes_comuna (
    comuna_id,
    numero_clientes
) SELECT
    cod_comuna,
    0
FROM
    rgl_cut ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comuna_id = 12201
```

It works but it's adding a new row for each registry on table_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
insert into table_com
  select id_b, code, 0
    from table_b where id_b not in (select id_com from table_com);
```

or this?

```
insert into table_com
  select id_b, code, 0
    from table_b where code not in (select code from table_com);
```

as I'm not clear on whether the deciding factor is the presence of the `id` or the `code`

Comment: I'll check this, if it works I'll pick it as correct because not changing columns properties (unique)

Comment: Jesus I love you! I change some id's because it wasn't that specifically what I need but that was the whole idea, to use the `not in (select` Hell, thanks! (I use the first code)

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `insert on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into a (code, value)
    select code, 0
    from b
    on duplicate key update code = values(code);
```

For this to work, you want a unique index/constraint on `a(code)`.

Comment: I edited my question with a comment for this answer.

Comment: Ah, I miss the `UPDATE`

Comment: It is inserting new registries for every registry in table_b, not only the ones which are not present in table_com

Comment: Yay! It works, I set that column as unique as you already said :D thanks!